# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/concurrent/BasicFuture.class

Tags: java, android-studio, build.gradle

I'm getting the following error.
I have not tried to solve it the last two days, but nothing had solved the problem.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/concurrent/BasicFuture.class

This is my build.grade

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project.logintest2"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.3.jar')
}
```

I have following two libraries:
- httpclient-4.5.1.jar
- http-4.4-3.jar

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in defaultConfig you need to add this below line to avoid error

```
// Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true

//like this
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project.logintest2"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
 multiDexEnabled true
    }
```